# Matching a binary matrix

Tags: integer-programming, finite-fields, algorithms

Given a MxN 0-1 matrix D, with the property that

1. both M and N are odd numbers
2. its row sums and column sums in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ field are all equal to the same number (0 or 1).

How do we find M binary numbers $r_i$ and N binary numbers $c_j$, such that $ \sum r_i = \sum c_j $ and 
$$
r_i + c_j = D_{ij}
$$ is satisfied for as many cell $(i,j)$ as possible? (By the way, the "+" is in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ field, that is the XOR operation.)

Comment: The constant columns and constant rows span a binary linear code $C$ of length $MN$ and dimension $M+N-1$ (the rank drops by one, because the all ones matrix can be written as a sum of rows as well as columns). It seems to me that you want to find a valid codeword of $C$ at the smallest possible Hamming distance from the received 'vector' $D$. In other words, you want to have a *complete* decoding algorithm for the code $C$. Need to think about this one ...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the constraint that $\sum r_i = \sum c_j$. Thanks for thinking about this problem.

Comment: What would be a good match for the identity matrix for you?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.05.04

Comment: Once you answer the above, consider circulant matrices in general.  What would be a good match for a circulant matrix? Or a row or column permutation of certain circulant matrices?  Gerhard "Ask Me About Binary Matrices" Paseman, 2012.05.05

Comment: For the $N \times N$ identity matrix, I suspect that an optimal solution is all $r_i = c_i = 0$, which has $N$ "wrong" cells.


Comment: Obvious comment: we can always get at least half of the cells satisfied. Set $c_i=0$ for all $i$. Then set $r_i=0$ or $r_i=1$ depending if row $i$ contains more zeros or ones

Comment: @TonyHuynh: Did you miss the constraint of $\sum r_i = \sum c_i$?

Comment: You can still almost get half.  If we choose $r$ uniformly from all vectors with $\frac{M+1}{2}$ nonzero entries, and $c$ uniformly from all vectors with $\frac{N \pm 1}{2}$ nonzero entries (sign chosen to match parity), then each cell has the correct sum with probability at least $\frac{MN-1}{2MN}$.  The expected number of matching cells is $\frac{MN}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$.  In general, I believe there are matrices where you can't match more than $1/2+\epsilon$ (e.g. random matrices) , but the original question seemed to be looking for an (Approx.?) algorithm instead of a bound over all matrices.

Comment: I'm glad many people find this problem interesting. Maybe I should mention where it come from. The original problem is the bulb switching problem: "Given a MxN matrix of bulbs, some are on and some are off. We can flip the switch of bulb (i,j) to toggle the state of all bulbs in row i and column j. What's the minimum number of flips to turn all bulbs off?" I used $x_{ij}$ to denote whether to flip the switch of bulb (i,j), and $r_i$, $c_j$ to denote the row sums and column sums of $x_{ij}$. I found unique solution when M,N are both even. For M,N both odd, it's reduced to the problem above.

Comment: Let $A$ be the $(M+N) \times (M+N)$ matrix which is $0$ in the upper left $M \times M$ and lower right $N \times N$ submatrix, and elsewhere has two copies of a matrix with entries $(-1)^{D_{ij}}$.  If we ignore the "equal sums" constraint, the problem is essentially asking you to find a $\pm 1$ vector $x$ which maximizes $x^TAx$.  For general $A$ this problem (the so-called "Binary Quadratic Optimization" problem) is hard to solve exactly.  My suspicion (though I don't have a proof for this) is that it remains hard to solve when restricted to the case where $A$ has the form in this problem.